# javascript confirm prompt crashes Chrome extension on Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension with a few js confirm prompts like this:

```
return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the order?");
```

On my windows PC it always works fine. On my Mac it always crashes my extension popup (and the confirm dialog never appears). Unless I step through it with Chrome developer tools--in which case it works fine 100% of the time and the confirm dialog displays and behaves correctly.

1. I have tried putting a `try/catch` around the confirm, which has no effect. The catch block is never entered.
2. I have tried running Chrome on the Mac from the command line, with switches to enable logging. I examined the log file after the crash. I saw lots of useless data in the log, but nothing relevant to my crash.
3. When I remove the **confirm()** it always works fine.
4. Instead of returning the result of the confirm directly, I tried setting `var foo = confirm("foobar");` -- and returning foo -- no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `alert()` or `prompt()`? Just wondering if it's something common to all the built-in dialogs.

Comment: Use the DOM dialog element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Comment: Daniel, I ended up taking your advice and scrapping all alerts and confirms in favor of the dialog element. All crashing problems gone. BTW, alerts were also crashing the mac. If you'll post your solution, I'll accept it, and maybe it will help others.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Makyen: I already did. There's nothing else I could put there.